# Bash for copying files committed by git

Tags: bash, git, ant, salesforce, commit

I would like to ask whether it is possible to do this:

**Folder 1**

- Class 1
- Class 2
- Class 3

**Folder 2**

- empty

Class 1 and Class 2 are modified, then committed to git repository (can work also for push). At this moment I need to automatically using bash script copy these two classes from Folder 1 to Folder 2. Eventually I also need to create an xml file where I will have something like:

```
<classes>
   Class 1
   Class 2
</classes>
```

But the xml is a second step and now I need to know whether is the first step even possible. I read about `git archive` but this would create an archive of the commit which is not what I need. Are there any other possibilities?

Thanks in advance,
David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> All this fuss should be used for deployment among certain environments. And I need to deploy only what was changed.

Then a `git diff --name-only @~ -- Folder1` is enough to give you a list of what has changed in Folder1.

From that list, your script can build the right `Folder2` content, and the right xml file.

Comment: That is actually not what I need. I don't need to create a copy of the Folder 1. All this fuss should be used for deployment among certain environments. And I need to deploy only what was changed. Therefore I need to copy only the changed files into a different folder, then adjust xml file describing the content of the deployment and once this is all done, I will just do the deployment - using another script which I have already prepared.

Comment: @DavidMartinka OK. I have rewritten the answer accordingly.